# Deleted Firestore documents still being retrieved

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have deleted some documents through a batch delete from a trigger in Cloud Functions. The console shows them as being deleted, however, my app still retrieves the docs! This has got to be a bug with firestore and it's a pretty major one. I found another user had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726374/documents-appear-after-being-deleted-in-firestore)

The path I'm using is `/users/{id}/timeline/{postId}`. I deleted a specific `postId`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you have the problem, that the app uses the cache and loads as well some documents from it. One thing you could try is to disable the offline persistence.

If you're using [Android with Real-Time Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) you could try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

[iOS + Real-Time Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

If you're using [FireStore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) then use the following:

Android:

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(false)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

iOS:

```
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false

// Any additional options
// ...

// Enable offline data persistence
let db = Firestore.firestore()
db.settings = settings
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Comment: @Tometoyou I don't know really but take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23908189/5508719

Comment: Also for Firestore is:   FirestoreSettings().isPersistenceEnabled = false

Comment: I'm doing this server-side, what's the option for that?

Comment: what do i need to import for this settings to work?

Answer (score 4):

Documents remain fetchable for a while after deletion. Their existence status rely on the DocumentSnapshot property - 'exists' and can be read and filtered in the pipe with snapshotChanges() method for docs and collections. See the example below:

```
...
.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((actions: DocumentChangeAction<T>[]) => {
          return actions
            .filter((a: DocumentChangeAction<T>) => a.payload.doc.exists)
            .map((a: DocumentChangeAction<T>) => {
              const data: T = {...a.payload.doc.data() as {}} as T;
              data['id'] = a.payload.doc.id;
              return data;
            });
        })
      );
```